# My ubuntu freezes only when I restart. It works fine when I bootup normally

Tags: boot, kubuntu, 22.04, freeze

When I boot up the laptop normally, it works fine. But if I restart it, it freezes on the boot screen showing the flashing kubuntu icon.

I have seen this message on: journalctl --since today.

`watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#2 stuck for 26s! [kworker/2:1:98]`

Also this

`Modules linked in: snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd> Mar 22 21:04:50 faiz-HP kernel:  processor_thermal_device cfg80211 processor_thermal_rfim mc ee1004 usbhid libarc4 hid_multitouch soundcore processor_thermal_mbox processor_thermal_rapl mei_me in> Mar 22 21:04:50 faiz-HP kernel: CPU: 2 PID: 98 Comm: kworker/2:1 Tainted: G        W         5.15.0-67-generic #74-Ubuntu Mar 22 21:04:50 faiz-HP kernel: Hardware name: HP HP Laptop 15s-fq2xxx/87FE, BIOS F.21 03/21/2022 Mar 22 21:04:50 faiz-HP kernel: Workqueue: events sof_probe_work [snd_sof] Mar 22 21:04:50 faiz-HP kernel: RIP: 0010:snd_hdac_bus_send_cmd+0xdf/0x130 [snd_hda_core]`

uname -a : `Linux faiz-HP 5.15.0-67-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 22 14:14:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

free -h :

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available Mem     7.4Gi       1.3Gi       4.4Gi       456Mi       1.7Gi       5.5Gi Swap:   2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi`

I restarted and it freezed.
How to diagnose this?

Comment: The message is pretty clear you have a CPU problem. Another message it is telling you is it appears to be a heat issue.

Comment: CPU cooling insufficient? ---> in the way to disaster?